# Memory Leak with NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray

I am trying to set up a multi-dimensional `NSMutableArray`. I am initially setting all position to a `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]` then replacing the object with another `[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]` (for example). When I am done I would like to rebuild the array. I am correct in saying `[array release]`? Will that release all the `NSNumber` objects? Or do I need to do more advance memory management, like set all objects to nil first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either release the array and recreate it or—slightly more efficiently—just call the array’s `-removeAllObjects`. The NSNumber objects you’re populating it with are autoreleased, so the array, by taking ownership of them when you add them to it, also assumes responsibility for releasing them when it itself gets released or has its contents removed.

Answer (score 2):

Your array will properly retain and release your `NSNumber`s as you add/replace and remove objects, as well as when you release the array holding the items. So yes you are correct since you are using the `NSNumber`s convenience constructor which will return an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 1):

Philosophically, you shouldn't know or care what the `NSArray` does with respect to retain and release. The extent of your contract with it is that `addObject:`/etc will put an object into the array and `objectAtIndex:`/etc will subsequently return the same objects. At most you need to consider whether you need to continue owning an object after putting it into an array, entirely according to your own requirements. `NSArray` is entirely responsible for its own memory management.

In the case of `NSArray`, how it manages retains and releases internally is well known and your literal question is already answered by Noah and Joe. But you should never, ever rely on another object having a specific implementation.

Comment: It's explicitly documented that NSArray will retain and release its elements. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html So that's part of its contract, one benefit of which is that you can use an array to own a dynamic number of objects without having to retain and release each object yourself and without relying on any unspecified implementation details. (All of this goes for dictionaries [keys are copied, objects are retained] and sets as well.)